# BigInteger scanner input in Java

Tags: java

I want to get only `BigInteger` from scanner input of Java,  but loop exceeds it's limit. If i want to get 2 times the input, the loop gets twice but prints only once. I want to get input and multiply the input and display results.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fastmultiplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int in = sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<BigInteger> al = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

        while ((sc.hasNextBigInteger()) && (sc1.hasNextBigInteger()) && (in != 0)) {
            in--;
            m = sc.nextBigInteger();
            n = sc1.nextBigInteger();
            al.add(m.multiply(n));

        }
        System.out.println(al.size());
        for (BigInteger integer : al) {

            System.out.println(integer);

        }
        sc.close();
        sc1.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you created two `Scanner` objects. But here is the required working code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fastmultiplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger m, n;
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int in = sc.nextInt();

            ArrayList<BigInteger> al = new ArrayList<>();
            while (in > 0) {
                in--;
                m = sc.nextBigInteger();
                n = sc.nextBigInteger();
                al.add(m.multiply(n));
            }

            al.stream().forEach((bigInteger) -> {
                System.out.println(bigInteger);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid user input.Going to terminate this program");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer , I have already tried this but SPOJ throws an RTE. if we enter strings the programme should terminate .

Comment: I have updated my answer. On wrong input, I have terminated this program. You can change the validation part according to yours if you want. The main issue in your question is loop exceeds it's limit.

Comment: thanks for correcting this ,but even with this code I am getting wrong answer . the problem is http://www.spoj.com/problems/MUL/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked . Could you please explain "al.stream().forEach " line?

Comment: Its a new feature in java 8. You can change it for loop if you are using older version. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html.